# Creating Tables with previous, current and next date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, spacebars

So this is what im doing, i have a carrousel with a header, also im using Meteor and Spacebars, so what im want to do, its in the header show dates in diferrentes Carrousels, let me try to explain,

```
<header yesterday go here>     <header today date go here>    <header tomorow gohere>          
    <carrousel 1 go heere>     <carrousel 2 go heere>`        <carrousel 3 go heere>  etc..
```

I have some ideas but not something specific, and i don't know why, but i think there is some kind of already carrousel who came with that function,already try something but all fail (thats why im not posting any of my code here is useless), so if you have some ideas it will be great

Comment: do you just need the coding of retrieving today's date?

Comment: hi cuSK, no im trying to show yesterday date, today date and tomorrow date, look at the web i put on the answer something like that

Comment: cuSK do you have code to retrieving todays date? on the template?

Comment: you could use http://www.datejs.com/, I don't have the exact code yet, but it might be: `Date.parse('yesterday');`, `Date.parse('today');`, and `Date.parse('tomorrow');`

Comment: It is very easy to get the dates of previous, current and next day. By the way in which format do you want the date's? I'm asking because I am not able to understand the format mentioned in [cerovaro](http://cerovaro.com). Should the format be like, "Thursday 6 Nov, 2014" or something like that?

Comment: yea that format its ok im using moment.js